# Swift - How to make a Label an AccessibilityElement with VoiceOver Turned Off?

Tags: ios, swift, label, accessibility

I'd like to make a certain Label an AccessibilityElement, however with Accessibility Voiceover turned off in an iOS app. I don't want this label to be read out when using VoiceOver.

QA team requires this label to be AccessibilityElement as their automated tests is referencing this by it's accessibilityIdentifier to the test the value in the label. Accessibility team on the other hands requires the value of this label not to be read out during VoiceOver.

Is there a way to approach this?

Currently, The label is currently in a stackview

And these are the properties of the label

```
private let priceLabel: Text16Left = {
        let label = Text16Left()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.isDynamicTypeEnabled = true
        label.isAccessibilityElement = true
        label.accessibilityIdentifier = AccessibilityIdentifiers.priceLabel
        return label
}()
```

Comment: Can you use `#if DEBUG` for QA team ? Or you can even make a separate build config / special flag for them

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign an `accessibilityIdentifier` to your views and make them reachable in UI tests without having to set their isAccessibilityElement property to true.

These days the `accessibilityIdentifier` is really more like a UI testing identifier. (I don't think accessibility actually pays any attention to it.)